# How to get Count values when changes Happen in FireBase DataBase using Swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, function, firebase, timer

I am new to swift Programming and FireBase,I have Implemented Chat Application,Which I stored the Message Count using sender and Receiver ID ,In receiver side getting count Perfectly,But when new count is added in FireBase I want to get that new count, for that I used timer to call a function every 10 seconds,i am getting count perfectly ,But My problem is Timer running continuously, App getting Hang and slow,After sometimes I doesn't response, can anyone suggest me how to call the function every 10 seconds or how to use timer.

Here I have tried this code,

```
var timer = Timer()
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        MessageCountingFunction()
    }
   func MessageCountingFunction(){
        //getting count details
        keyvalue.removeAllObjects()
    countarray.removeAllObjects()
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("CountDetails").child(AuthManager.User.id.value).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let cakeSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for cakes in cakeSnapshot {
                    print(cakes)
                    if let cakeDictionary = cakes.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {
                        print(cakeDictionary)
                        let count = cakeDictionary["Count"]
                        let key = cakes.key as String
                        //your class that takes a key as String and a Dictionary
                        print(count as Any)
                        print(key)
                        self.keyvalue.add(key)
                        self.countarray.add(count!)

                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                    print(self.keyvalue)
                    print(self.countarray)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        })
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.MessageCountingFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    }
```

Comment: remove timer and change in observe events closure like  FIRDataEventType.childAdded

Comment: can u please change the above code ..and where I call this function

Comment: when I add FIRDataEventType.childAdded I didn't get anything from database

Comment: this is not the solution you should not have to call the method in 10 second, when ever new message is added to database you will get the callback , basically whenever you will push new message you have to add the key  to maintain the message is new or not.basically you are using "observeSingleEvent" so it will not work as a observer. it will work only one time. you will not get any callback after one time if you will use observeSingleEvent.

Comment: for this what code I should add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My json data structure for new message is :-

1. { "status" : "sent", "sender" : "ayush ", "timeStamp" :
   1525760473513 }

we are maintaining the status key for checking new message. after reading we are updating value of status key to read and looking for sent status for new message.

```
var channelRef: DatabaseReference =   Database.database().reference().child(FIREBASE_CONSULTATION_DBKEY)     

channelRef.child("channelKey").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in // 1
        if let channelData = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{ // 2
            let id = snapshot.key
            self.chatMessageArray.removeAll()
            for (key,obj) in channelData{
               if status == "Sent"{


                }
            }
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: good ..but please think which one is best solution 1.you will asking in every 10 second for new message is there or not. 2. database itself will notify you when new message will come.(firebase is a real time database)